# Visual Studio 2015 Project Folder Access Denied - Non TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, access-denied

I'm a SQL / BI Developer by profession.  I've written a few C# apps for my employer to expand my skill-set...it can't hurt right?

Anyway, down to business.

Since yesterday I've really been struggling to build a dashboard using any form of graph / charting tools.

I downloaded ZedGraph and tried the .NET framework Chart Control (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting).  I keep getting an "Access Denied" error to my Visual Studio "Project\obj\app.exe" folder when the compiler tries to write the executable file.
I've literally searched dozens of forums and every solution I've tried hasn't solved my problem.  If I delete the entire project from my Visual Studio 2015 folder and recreate it with the same name, without adding anything to the fresh project, it still fails to build.
It's almost as if there's a cache somewhere, but I can't find it.  I thought the cache location was in one of the Microsoft folders in my AppData folder, but it's not.  I even deleted the project folders in Visual Studio 2015\Backup Files.

I can't change the folder attributes either.  If I disable the read-only folder attribute on the Visual Studio 2015 folder and all subfolders and files, the system resets the attributes when the Properties dialog is closed.

I deleted everything in my Temp folder, stopped and restarted the VsHub services countless times, reset my Visual Studio environment settings (Import and Export), but the solution just doesn't build.

Any help would be great.  I don't really want to do a system restore.

Here's the error message I keep receiving:

Cannot open 'C:\Users*user*\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewProj\NewProj\obj\Debug\NewProj.exe' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\Users*user*\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewProj\NewProj\obj\Debug\NewProj.exe' is denied.'  NewProj C:\Users*user*\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NewProj\NewProj\CSC

I am part of the Administrators group on my local PC and I've tried running Visual Studio as Administrator, but this doesn't solve the issue :(

I'm literally out of solutions...

Can anyone suggest anything that'll solve my problem?

Comment: have you tried changing the directory of the project's folder and then reloaded it from there ? (I.E on another drive or something you have full access to)

Comment: If I look into my TFS-Class it says for *ClientCacheDirecotryForInstance* : "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\<version>\Cache\" . Try to rename this directory

Answer (score 0):

My only idea would be to recreate the project in a folder where you shurely have acess to ( like in an extra folder on the desktop ). Im shure that theres a better solution but thats all i got ;D

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging. I tried all the suggested solutions before posting the question. Regardless of looking for cache folders and using different file locations that I KNEW had write access...none of that worked. Turns out it was BitDefender. It saw Visual Studio projects as malware :|

Needless to say, when creating the .exe file while the code was compiling, BitDefender blocked the creation of it, thereby causing the error.
I added my Visual Studio and SQL folders to the exceptions list and was able to create my projects afterwards.
The only thing I need to figure out now is how to create a solution with a name I previously used, even after I shift-deleted the project from my Visual Studio folder(s).  Could this be a registry entry?